# Open whatsapp//: in webview

Tags: android, android-webview

I need the whatsapp chat to open when clicking on any phone number. I have the following code but the application closes and I can't do it
Can you help me? thanks

```
  myWebView.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient(){
  @Override
  public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url) {
    boolean overrideUrlLoading = false;

    if( url.startsWith("http:") || url.startsWith("https:") ) {
        return false;
    }

    if( url.startsWith("tel:") || url.startsWith("mailto:") ||(url != null && url.startsWith("whatsapp://"))  ) {
        view.getContext().startActivity(new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse(url)));
        overrideUrlLoading = true;


        Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse(url));
        startActivity(intent);
    }
    return true;

 }
 });
myWebView.loadUrl("https://midominio.es");
```

Screenshot:

[image]

```
 android.content.ActivityNotFoundException: No Activity found to handle Intent { act=android.intent.action.VIEW dat=whatsapp://617560187 }
        at android.app.Instrumentation.checkStartActivityResult(Instrumentation.java:2051)
        at android.app.Instrumentation.execStartActivity(Instrumentation.java:1709)
        at android.app.Activity.startActivityForResult(Activity.java:5192)
        at android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity.startActivityForResult(FragmentActivity.java:767)
        at android.app.Activity.startActivityForResult(Activity.java:5150)
        at android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity.startActivityForResult(FragmentActivity.java:754)
        at android.app.Activity.startActivity(Activity.java:5521)
        at android.app.Activity.startActivity(Activity.java:5489)
        at es.shop.shopyshop.principal$2.shouldOverrideUrlLoading(principal.java:64)
        at android.webkit.WebViewClient.shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebViewClient.java:83)
        at Dx.a(PG:1)
        at ic.a(PG:22)
        at org.chromium.android_webview.AwContentsClientBridge.shouldOverrideUrlLoading(PG:152)
        at android.os.MessageQueue.nativePollOnce(Native Method)
        at android.os.MessageQueue.next(MessageQueue.java:336)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:174)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7356)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:492)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:930)
```

Comment: "the application closes". does it crash? do you have a stacktrace?

Comment: There is no error in the console, it just closes

Comment: @njzk2 Attach picture with the problem in my question

Answer (score 0):

You should be aware that `startActivity()` will throw an [ActivityNotFoundException](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/ActivityNotFoundException) if there's no app that matches your intent, which is what you experience as uncaught exception will terminate your app:

> This exception is thrown when a call to Context#startActivity or one of its variants fails because an Activity can not be found to execute the given Intent:

Wrap it with usual `try/catch`.

```
try {
    startActivity(intent);
} catch (Exception e) {
   // handle error case
}
```

Also it's pretty unlikely that there's nothing related to that crash in logcat

Comment: OK, I'm something new in this. It marks the following errors. Attached errors in my question

Comment: This is exactly the casw i wrote about

Comment: Please do not edit the question and not correct the code there as further readers will be confused what is this all about in the first place. I reverted your last edit. If my answer solved your problem, please accept it.

Comment: As for code - it's advised to not leave `catch ` block empty - this silence the error and simply confuse end user as he got no idea why things do not work. At least show a Toast saying i.e. "No application to handle xxx protocol'. Or split this code block into separate blocks or make your toast being more user friendly (i.e. if that's 'mailto:' that failed, say "no mail application found'. if that 'whatsapp:' then say 'no Whatsapp found" etc

Comment: then check the stacktrace again to see why and where exactly (you will get file and line)